# Remove an item from step function output

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-step-functions

When passing inputs from one state to another, is there a way to remove a particular Key-value from the input event?
For example:
I need to remove `CurrentSubAccountChunkResults` key and value from the input before passing it to the next state of the step function.
I read I could specify Parameters to filter out.
Rather than specifying all the parameters I need , I am trying to find a way to  remove what I do not need in the input and pass the rest to the next state.
Could someone help me with any ideas they might have?

```
{
"Item1": { item: No1, item: No2 },
"Item2": "iam-item2",
"Item3": 3,
"Item4": { item: No4, item: No5 },
"CurrentSubAccountChunkResults" : { "result1": "iam-result1" },
"VerificationResults": { "final-result1": "iam-result1" }
}
```

Comment: Please use properly formatted code blocks, not screenshots for your code nor errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your options are:

1. A Lambda task to remove unwanted keys and values
2. Two pass tasks to redact values, but not the keys

Here's the non-Lambda option.  The first Pass task adds the "private" key names you want to redact.  The second Pass uses the `JsonMerge` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) to merge `payload` and `private`.

```json
{
  "StartAt": "AddPrivateFields",
  "States": {
    "AddPrivateFields": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "payload.$": "$",
        "private": {
          "CurrentSubAccountChunkResults": null
        }
      },
      "Next": "Redact"
    },
    "Redact": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "redacted.$": "States.JsonMerge($.payload, $.private, false)"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

If the two objects in the merge function (`"States.JsonMerge($.payload, $.private, false)"`) share keys, the values in the second will take precedence.  This sets the `private` keys to `null` in the output:

```json
{
 "redacted": {
   "CurrentSubAccountChunkResults": null,
   "Item1": {
     "item": "No1",
     "item2": "No2"
   },
   "Item2": "iam-item2",
   "Item3": 3,
   "Item4": {
     "item": "No4",
     "item2": "No5"
   },
   "VerificationResults": {
     "final-result1": "iam-result1"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: this is a great idea, and it does redact the data, though the element is still there which isn't completely clean. Thanks for showing the code.